# Angularjs best practices for implementing multiple directives with common functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My page will have a growing list of directives that have common functionality. What would be the best way to implement that functionality keeping best practices and performance in mind.

For example:

Page will have 100 directives and each directive will have common events:

1. Show hidden layer on mouseover
2. Hide div > view and Show div > edit on click.

......

Template:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="view">
        <div class="edit-controls hidden">
            <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        </div>
        <h3>{{......}}</h3>
        <p>{{.....}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="edit hidden">
        <form>
            ........
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Option 1. Directive:

```
appModule.directive('elemTest', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '.......',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('mouseover', function() {
                element.find(".edit-controls").show();
            });

            element.on('mouseout', function() {
                element.find(".edit-controls").hide();
            });

            element.find(".edit").on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                element.children(".view").hide();
                element.children(".edit").show();
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Option 2. Directive with no link functions but handle mouseover/out/click events with jQuery script snippet on the bottom of the page:

```
$(".panel").live('mouseover',function() { 
    .......
}) 

$(".panel").live('mouseout',function() { 
    .......
}) 

..........
```

Option 3. Directive with controller and ng-click instead of directives link function?

Option 4. ?

Comment: Break common directive functionality into its own directive. You can always put more than one directive on each element as an attribute.

Comment: Thanks, Zack. That's a great suggestion since I am going to have different directives all sharing common on events!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Angular 1.2.0

Option 4: Directives with support for ng-mouseover, ng-mouseout (mouseleave?) and an ng-click on the edit button.

In a nutshell, make your directive have a template which supports the functions:

In the template:

```
...
<div ng-mouseover="showEditControls = true" ng-mouseleave="showEditControls = false">
 <div ng-show="showEditControls">
  <button ng-click="edit()" />
 </div>
</div>
...
```

In the directive:

```
...
controller: function($scope){
 $scope.edit = function()
  // do whatever the editor does
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can see the benefits of using ng-mouseover and -mouseleave in this case. However, why use a controller for an event that makes no changes to the model? Is not link function a better place for event listeners? I am speaking of:  
           element.find(".edit").on('click',....

Comment: If you need the view to change, bind those view objects to a scope variable thats controlled by some other part of the view. In your example things with `.view` get hidden and `.edit` are shown. When edit is clicked, just change their ng-show expressions to false and true respectively.